# evaluating a string in csh

Tags: shell-script, csh

script1 is as follows

```
#!/bin/csh
echo $*
$*
```

Then I run the following on command line:

```
>script1 setenv VAR "/user/path" \; ls
```

It gives output as:

```
setenv VAR /user/path ; ls
setenv: Too many arguments.
```

Any ideas to fix it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to acomplish?

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand why you would want this but your problem is that you're trying to run a variable instead of evaluating it. Try this instead:

```
#!/bin/csh
echo "$*"
eval "$*"
```

Then

```
script1 setenv VAR "/user/path" \; ls
```

I don't know `csh` but the problem seems to be related to having two commands as a variable. This works as expected:

```
setenv aa "ls"
"$aa"
```

But this fails and needs the `eval`:

```
setenv aa "ls; echo foo"
"$aa"
```